# Installing Django-channels error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop a chat application in Django on mac OS.
I've tried to install Django-Channels in virtualenv, with this commands:

```
pip install channels

pip install django-channels
```

but this error occurred:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4c/xy3rtg_165l0650j4tq7fvrh0000gn/T/pip-install-7anqvzhg/twisted/

Python version = 3.5.2,
Django version = 1.11,
pip is already up-tp-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem will be solved if you have updated your pip

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved when I install visual C++ build tool.

Comment: how did you install it?

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me if you are using mac

xcode-select --install

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem, and this fixed it.

Inside of virtual environment,

`pip install incremental` then `pip install channels`

you can check that it worked by running

`python3 -c 'import channels; print(channels.__version__)'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have outdated version of setup tools.
try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```